# Event fired before product save

Tags: product, event-observer

This event will work before saving the product because i need one observer which will work before product save.
"catalog_product_prepare_save"

Comment: Do you mean you need another event that fires before a product is saved?

Comment: I am asking this event will work.I tried but its not working before product saving.

Comment: Please reform your question with some added code. For example how are you saving the object (code or backend) and what should this event trigger. Did you build a custom extension that uses this observer, if so post some code like the model and/or the config.xml. We will need more info to help you with your question

Answer (score 7):

The event `catalog_product_prepare_save` will only be called when changing products via the api or the admin section. It is called in the following places:

1. app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php
2. app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Option/Api.php

If you want to catch all product saves then I would suggest using the event `catalog_product_save_before`. This is fired by the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php` so if you call $product->save() somewhere in the code then you will get this event.